# Number of pairs of Binary Strings of Length n with Hamming Distance b

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

What is the maximum number of pairs of $k\geq2$ distinct binary strings of length $n$, such that the strings in each pair are at Hamming distance $b$? In other words, given $k$ points on the $n$-dimensional Boolean hypercube, how many of these can possibly be at distance $b$ of each other?

I have a trivial upper bound given by $k \min\{\binom{n}{b},k\}$ simply because each string can have at most $\binom{n}{b}$ neighbors at distance $b$. Does anybody know how to better upper bound this quantity?

Comment: Do you want all the strings to be pairwise at distance $b$? So for $n=5, b=2$ an answer would be $\{10000,11100,11010,10110\}$?  This may not be maximal.

Comment: I think it might not always be possible to have all $k$ strings at pairwise distance $b$ like in your example, because e.g. you cannot have more than $n$ neighbors at distance 1. So I would like to have as many as possible at pairwise distance $b$

Comment: I was trying to understand the question.  If I read the first sentence literally, I could split the $2^n$ strings into pairs, with each string at distance $b$ from its mate, and get $2^{n-1} pairs.  I don't know for sure this is possible, but I think so.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: @Ross' suggestion is easy to make work. Take a fixed string $w$ of weight $b$, and pair up the strings $u$ and $u+b$ for all $u$. Here $u+b$ is the componentwise modulo 2 sum (=bitwise XOR).